# Determination of the most acidic hydrogen in an organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, stability, resonance

> Identify the most acidic hydrogen in the compound below:
>
> [image: 2‐nitro‐[1,1'‐biphenyl]‐4,4'‐diol]

Can someone please explain why is $\ce{H^\mathrm{a}}$ in the compound below more acidic than $\ce{H^\mathrm{b}}$?

This is what is written in the answer key although the conjugate base obtained from losing $\ce{H^\mathrm{b}}$ is stabilized by both resonance, and the inductive electron withdrawing nitro group.

Comment: Anion without Hb is _not_ stabilized by resonance. NO2 is in the wrong position with respect to that OH.

Comment: It is stabilized by resonance due to the phenol ring. The stabilizing role of the nitro group is inductive.

Comment: Well, actually the stabilizing role of NO2 is not just inductive.

Comment: Well, another way of looking at it is that the Nitro group is ortho to the ring at the right, and thus decreases electron density in that ring.